# [MAKE]: How to run function based on passed arg

Tags: makefile, command-line-arguments, gnu-make

I am currently working on project with multiple services, so I figured that creating make to manage them would be a nice thing, since I'm new to make I am wondering how to achieve following thing.

Currently I have couple of scripts to view logs from given service containers. Here is example command below:

```
logs-back: 
  docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yaml logs --follow backend
```

Since there are about 12 services I had to make 12 separate commands to view logs from specific ones.

What I would like to know is how to create more generic command which would view logs from specific service using service alias as argument, something like this:

```
logs: 
  docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yaml logs --follow $(arg)
```

and used like

`make run back` - where back would be this arg

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
logs-%: 
        docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yaml logs --follow $*
```

Now you can run this:

```
make logs-back
```

and make will find that pattern rule matches the target on the command line, and use it with the automatic variable `$*` set to the string that matches the stem (the part matching `%`).

See the [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html) for the meaning of all the terms in the previous paragraph :)

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer:

```
make logs arg=back
```

This would create and populate a variable in the makefile named `arg`, such that `$(arg)` would expand to `back`.

Using the bareword `back` on the command line tells make to build a target named `back`.   This leads to the next possibility:

```
LOGS := back front side top bottom
.PHONY: $(LOGS)

$(LOGS):
    docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yaml logs --follow $@
```

where you would run `make back`, to generate the `back` logfile.