# Makefile executing commands based on target's name

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have to execute commands as follows:

```
tc1 : ./a.exe
   ./a.exe < ./tc1.txt
tc2 : ./a.exe
   ./a.exe < ./tc2.txt
..
```

and so on.
I can repeat it obviously, but I cant find a solution to make the target's name as variable and use it to execute the command. What I want is something like this,

```
tc${i} : ./a.exe
    ./a.exe < ./tc${i}.txt
```

How can I achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: Does ["How to run function based on passed arg"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75161281/14403369) answer your question?

Comment: Thanks, this actually solved one problem but gave rise to another. This type of using "-%" and "$*" does not seem to support when I want to call another target from this variable target. Like `tc-%: another target` does not get executed. What should I do to maintain variable name and also call another target?

Comment: You should ask another question with test code reproducing the problem you observe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GNU Make manual describes [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html), which is apparently what you're looking for.

This should work:

```
RESULTS = tc1 tc2 tc3 ...

$(RESULTS) : ./a.exe
        ./a.exe < ./$@.txt
```

Comment: Yup thanks. I did the same thing.